# Jquery JSON response is undefined

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, response

I have a script that makes an ajax call to a php file, the php file returns two values, a lat and a long.

The ajax response is correct, when checking in firebug I get this response:

```
[{"latitude":"-0.758623","longitude":"52.047870"}]
```

This is the code I am using to make the call, what I dont understand is why `response.latitude` and `response.longitude` are returned as undefined:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://www.url.com/route/findRoute",
        data: {postcode: postCode},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response)
            {
                alert(response.longitude);
            }
        });
```

Please can anyone point me in the right direction?

Many thanks

Jim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the response is an array. You can loop through all elements like so

```
response.forEach(function(data){
    console.log(data.latitude);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know it had already converted to an array, I assumed because it was a single request it would natively be and object of one level

Answer (score 3):

it is array you have to loop like this:

```
$.each(response,function(index,item){

    console.log(item);

});
```

**or if it will always be single item then you can access first index like this:**

```
console.log(reponse[0].latitude);
condole.log(reponse[0].longitude);
```

[**WORKING FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/K8kjN/)

Comment: Thanks, rethought because it waves single result it would be a single object returned but (obviously now) it's an array of objects!

Comment: if its array of objects then go with looping it using ``$.each`` or ``$.map``